# How can I fold each word in a header?

Tags: code-folding, header-line

I'd like to fold each word in a header in org-mode. In other words, I'd like to toggle between this view:

```
* emacs is fun
```

and this view :

```
* e i f
```

and hopefully toggle each word like :

```
* e is f
```

or

```
* e i fun
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dan , I have some huge headers with lots of items (words) squeezed in it, and I almost remember some of the items, so being able to see their initials are enough most of the time--but still want to check the whole word quickly if necessary. And those huge headers occupy the whole frame, so I thought folding/unfolding each/all words might come in really handy. I have less screen space in height so having separate headers for those words and folding/unfolding them didn't work.

Comment: Here is a semi-related example of how to modify the built-in folding of text in `org-mode`, which includes tab cycling -- **Completely hide the :PROPERTIES: drawer in org-mode** -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode  However, what you seek is complex and not advisable as it would take quite a bit of work to iron out all the kinks.  I wouldn't attempt it, but perhaps someone in the audience will be motivated or you can add a bounty after a certain period of time if there are no takers.